# Simple text editor for winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a MDI application, I need to add a text editor form to it which can do something like what NotePad does! I wonder if there is already such a Form that I can simply add to my MDI form (I know I sound lazy!)

Or I have to do it all myself :( !!!

Comment: How about an own form which contains a RichTextBox??

Comment: This one should be really easy, (rich)textbox + menu + some event handlers

Comment: Why don't you use TextBox with multiline property set to true? Notepad is just that.

Comment: I know, I was wondering if I can skip writing code for all menu items like new save load print...!

Comment: Uh, guess what Notepad is? [it's just a big multiline textbox](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=raymond+chen+award+notepad&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CE0QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Foldnewthing%2Farchive%2F2009%2F11%2F02%2F9915989.aspx&ei=VEj8TsDtJoaCOovorJoB&usg=AFQjCNF-cZIh0RWkDKpKOoIdRhx_ENGmxg&sig2=oUDlxDsR0KTqY-8IYqE4sA).

Comment: @Lucian, sorry that I didn't see your comment before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as others told you from your description it looks like a multiline textbox would do the trick, sometimes such control is called TextArea and allows you to show vertical and horizontal scrollbars as needed.

if you use a RichTextBox then you can have RTF text in it, so bold, italic, underlined and other formatting options that are actually not supported in NotePad, NotePad++, TextPad etc.

if you decide to stick on pure TEXT format and not RTF one of the best control to handle this is available here for free: [Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)

the features and possibilities with this great control are endless, like code formatting, collapsable regions and much, much more.